# Create different url link for each element in array

Tags: php

I have it so people enter their name into a database and it tracks all their data for this game. I'd like to make a page that lists all the users currently in the database. 
I'm just echoing them out right now:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
echo $row['Username'] ;
```

I need to make it so when you click on one of them it redirects you to a url called:
`profile.php?name=WHATEVERNAMETHEYCLICKED`

Hope this was enough info. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is not a coding service. What's your problem ? Your loop is ready, do you have any problem ?

Comment: echo '<a href="profile.php?name=<?= $row['Username'] ?>"><?= $row['Username'] ?></a>

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
    echo '<a href="profile.php?name='.urlencode($row['Username']).'">'.$row['Username'].'</a>'; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks :) easier then I thought.